# "field was not set" instead of specific error message in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, message

I am using codeigniter form validation rules.Instead of showing me correct error message it is showing "Field was not set". I want to show error related to field name.

This is my code.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('project_name', 'Project Name', 'trim|required');
```

how to show that "Firstbane is required" or something default of codeigniter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you grab some code from 3rd party? Do you develop on clean CI install? There is no other explanation but you are using modified errors.

Comment: did you load the form validation library? $this->load->library('form_validation');

Comment: @Kyslik I did not get your point. I did not get any 3rd party.

Comment: @cartalot yes I am loading library thats why errors are coming.

Comment: my suggestion would be to get a different perspective --  use the code from the codeigniter manual tutorial or another tutorial. if that doesn't work then its a server or config issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it as follow:

I have "xampp" installed, with the option "[short_open_tag=false](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)" in the "php.ini" file. I have the package of spanish language installed, too. This one have "validation_lang.php" file in the path "system/laguage/spanish"  (I'm Spaniard)  and it start with "<?" short tag. Well, I changed the "<?" by "<?php". Later, my program worked.

I hope it can help you.

Excuse me my bad English!

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but I am working on live server and I do not have any other language installed just a "english" folder and within it a file named "form_validation_lang.php" and it is starting with "<?php" . I am still stucked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom error message with `set_message` and use the label from the `set_rules` function. You can find the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors).

Here is an example:

```
// Set the validation rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('project_name', 'Project Name', 'trim|required');

// Set the custom message with %s where the label should go
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s is required. Please enter a value.');

// For an invalid project_name, you will get the error:
// Project Name is required. Please enter a value.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case user3110655, I got the same issue when using another language than english with system language files downloaded over the web.
All files were good, except form_validation one.
Keys wasn't written like the english file and tag wasn't with %s as expected.
If using a language file, double check that your file is correctly written like the english one provided by code igniter.